# sql date related query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table and one row in it. When I use this following query:

`SELECT FROM ROOM WHERE chk_in = '7-APR-14';`

it shows no data. Any idea where i am going wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE room (
r_id   number(5),
book_date    date,
chk_in  date,
chk_out  date,
r_ct_id    number(6),
booking_id    number(5),
c_id    number(9),
primary key (r_id),
foreign key (booking_id) references booking_info(booking_id),
foreign key (c_id) references customer(c_id)
);


INSERT INTO room VALUES (61276,'4-FEB-14','7-APR-14','4-APR-14',87689,19857,987987987);
```

Comment: I can't even run your CREATE table statement. Inserting '4-FEB-14' gives me error because MySQL couldn't recognize this dateformat.

Answer (score 2):

If your column type of `chk_in` is `date` then use-

```
SELECT FROM ROOM WHERE chk_in = STR_TO_DATE('7-APR-14', '%d/%l/%Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper format for date.  Assuming `chk_in` is a `date` with no time component:

```
WHERE chk_in = '2014-04-07'
```

If there is a time component, use an inequality:

```
WHERE chk_in >= '2014-04-07' and
      chk_in < date_add('2014-04-07', interval 1 day)
```

The inequality makes it possible for MySQL to use an index on `chk_in` for the query.